# Local Video Not Shown on first time in react-native-agora IOS but work for react native android

Tags: android, react-native, agora.io

## I'm facing issue in react-native-ios, can't able to see first time local video when calling through react-native-agora. In react-native android its work showing both local and remote video.

> when I toogle video then it work fine for rendering local video screen on right side corner top side on remote video screen. but first time when video call receive it not render local video screen.

```js
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, NativeModules, ScrollView, Text, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { RtcEngine, AgoraView } from 'react-native-agora';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const { Agora } = NativeModules;                  //Define Agora object as a native module

const {
  FPS30,
  AudioProfileDefault,
  AudioScenarioDefault,
  Adaptative,
} = Agora;                                        //Set defaults for Stream

class Video extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      peerIds: [],                                //Array for storing connected peers
      uid: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),       //Generate a UID for local user
      appid: this.props.AppID,                    //Enter the App ID generated from the Agora Website
      channelName: this.props.ChannelName,        //Channel Name for the current session
      vidMute: false,                             //State variable for Video Mute
      audMute: false,                             //State variable for Audio Mute
      joinSucceed: false,                         //State variable for storing success
    };
    const config = {                            //Setting config of the app
      appid: this.state.appid,                  //App ID
      channelProfile: 0,                        //Set channel profile as 0 for RTC
      videoEncoderConfig: {                     //Set Video feed encoder settings
        width: 720,
        height: 1080,
        bitrate: 1,
        frameRate: FPS30,
        orientationMode: Adaptative,
      },
      audioProfile: AudioProfileDefault,
      audioScenario: AudioScenarioDefault,
    };
    RtcEngine.init(config);                     //Initialize the RTC engine
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    RtcEngine.on('userJoined', (data) => {
      const { peerIds } = this.state;             //Get currrent peer IDs
      if (peerIds.indexOf(data.uid) === -1) {     //If new user has joined
        this.setState({
          peerIds: [...peerIds, data.uid],        //add peer ID to state array
        });
      }
    });
    RtcEngine.on('userOffline', (data) => {       //If user leaves
      this.setState({
        peerIds: this.state.peerIds.filter(uid => uid !== data.uid), //remove peer ID from state array
      });
    });
    RtcEngine.on('joinChannelSuccess', (data) => {                   //If Local user joins RTC channel
      RtcEngine.startPreview();                                      //Start RTC preview
      this.setState({
        joinSucceed: true,                                           //Set state variable to true
      });
    });
    RtcEngine.joinChannel(this.state.channelName, this.state.uid);  //Join Channel
    RtcEngine.enableAudio();                                        //Enable the audio
  }
  /**
  * @name toggleAudio
  * @description Function to toggle local user's audio
  */
  toggleAudio() {
    let mute = this.state.audMute;
    console.log('Audio toggle', mute);
    RtcEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(!mute);
    this.setState({
      audMute: !mute,
    });
  }
  /**
  * @name toggleVideo
  * @description Function to toggle local user's video
  */
  toggleVideo() {
    let mute = this.state.vidMute;
    console.log('Video toggle', mute);
    this.setState({
      vidMute: !mute,
    });
    RtcEngine.muteLocalVideoStream(!this.state.vidMute);
  }
  /**
  * @name endCall
  * @description Function to end the call
  */
  endCall() {
    RtcEngine.destroy();
    Actions.home();
  }
  /**
  * @name peerClick
  * @description Function to swap the main peer videostream with a different peer videostream
  */
  peerClick(data) {
    let peerIdToSwap = this.state.peerIds.indexOf(data);
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let currentPeers = [...prevState.peerIds];
      let temp = currentPeers[peerIdToSwap];
      currentPeers[peerIdToSwap] = currentPeers[0];
      currentPeers[0] = temp;
      return { peerIds: currentPeers };
    });
  }
  /**
  * @name videoView
  * @description Function to return the view for the app
  */
  videoView() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {
          this.state.peerIds.length > 1
            ? <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <View style={{ height: dimensions.height * 3 / 4 - 50 }}>
                <AgoraView style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  remoteUid={this.state.peerIds[0]} mode={1} key={this.state.peerIds[0]} />
              </View>
              <View style={{ height: dimensions.height / 4 }}>
                <ScrollView horizontal={true} decelerationRate={0}
                  snapToInterval={dimensions.width / 2} snapToAlignment={'center'} style={{ width: dimensions.width, height: dimensions.height / 4 }}>
                  {
                    this.state.peerIds.slice(1).map((data) => (
                      <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: dimensions.width / 2, height: dimensions.height / 4 }}
                        onPress={() => this.peerClick(data)} key={data}>
                        <AgoraView style={{ width: dimensions.width / 2, height: dimensions.height / 4 }}
                          remoteUid={data} mode={1} key={data} />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))
                  }
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
            </View>
            : this.state.peerIds.length > 0
              ? <View style={{ height: dimensions.height - 50 }}>
                <AgoraView style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  remoteUid={this.state.peerIds[0]} mode={1} />
              </View>
              : <Text>No users connected</Text>
        }
        {
          !this.state.vidMute                                              //view for local video
            ? <AgoraView style={styles.localVideoStyle} zOrderMediaOverlay={true} showLocalVideo={true} mode={1} />
            : <View />
        }
        <View style={styles.buttonBar}>
          <Icon.Button style={styles.iconStyle}
            backgroundColor="#0093E9"
            name={this.state.audMute ? 'mic-off' : 'mic'}
            onPress={() => this.toggleAudio()}
          />
          <Icon.Button style={styles.iconStyle}
            backgroundColor="#0093E9"
            name="call-end"
            onPress={() => this.endCall()}
          />
          <Icon.Button style={styles.iconStyle}
            backgroundColor="#0093E9"
            name={this.state.vidMute ? 'videocam-off' : 'videocam'}
            onPress={() => this.toggleVideo()}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return this.videoView();
  }
}

let dimensions = {                                            //get dimensions of the device to use in view styles
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonBar: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#0093E9',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
  },
  localVideoStyle: {
    width: 140,
    height: 160,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 5,
    right: 5,
    zIndex: 100,
  },
  iconStyle: {
    fontSize: 34,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingLeft: 40,
    paddingRight: 40,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
});

export default Video;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the `enableVideo` function along with the enable audio function.
startPreview is used when you need to display the local video before joining the channel. And should be disabled after successfully joining the channel.

> Note: This version of SDK(v2) is deprecated and not encouraged to be used. Please switch to v3.